# If I have a text file with a list of names, how can I sort this list by their last names first using C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, text-files

I'm trying to write a program that will read a text file with a list of names listed like

Michael Jordan

Kobe Bryant

Larry Bird

Lebron James

I've written the code to open the file and rewrite the file and included it.

Once Loaded how can I sort this list by Last Name and then by First name?

```
List<string> cstrName = new List<string>();

    private void Sorter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Load the array with the data in the file
            FileStream nameFile = new FileStream("input.txt",FileMode.Open); 

            StreamReader nameStreamReader = new StreamReader(nameFile);
            while (nameStreamReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                cstrName.Add(nameStreamReader.ReadLine());
            }//End Loop
            nameFile.Close();      //Close file
        }
        //Sets an error message if there is an issue opening the file
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Opening File. Data not loaded " + 
            ex.Message,"File Not Found",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
     private void btnSortByName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        {
            cstrName.Sort();
        }

        //display names in a list box
        displayNames();
     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("input2.txt", cstrName);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap your `cstrName.Sort();` for

```
cstrName = cstrName.OrderBy(x => x.Split(' ').Last()).ToList();
```

Make sure you have `Using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

It orders cstrName by the last word in the string (working out words by splitting the string by spaces ' ').

Comment: Ok great! Would I just change .last to .first and repeat if I wanted to sort by first name using this sequence?